# Уникальное значение в массиве Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан массив чисел, в котором одно значение уникальное, а все остальные повторяются. Примеры массивов:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
[ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]
[ 3, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3 ]
```

Что я делаю:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    result = arr[0]
    for number in arr:
        if arr[number] == result:
            continue
        else:
            result = arr[number]
    return result
```

Алгоритм простой, вот только возникает ошибка:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Я нигде не использую деление, чтобы получился `float`. Из `float` у меня только возможный элемент массива, никак не индекс. В чем может быть проблема?

**P.S. Нашел ошибку в логике алгоритма, вот только почему остается TypeError - не понятно.**

Comment: *Примеры массивов* Массивы имеют строго такой тип - все элементы, кроме одного, идентичны?

Comment: да, только одно уникальное, все остальные повторяются.

Comment: list(set(arr)) - и не надо никаких циклов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки что ж тут непонятного?

```
for number in arr:             # [ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]
    if arr[number] == result:  # в один прекрасный момент получится arr[0.55]
```

Ну и в принципе алгоритм со своей задачей не справляется.

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    return arr[0] if arr.count(arr[0]) == 1 else sum(arr) - arr.count(arr[0]) * arr[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужен просто список уникальных элементов, то вот так можно попробовать:

```
a1 = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
a2 = [ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]
a3 = [ 3, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3 ]

res=set(a1+a2+a3)
print (res)
```

Результат будет таким:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 0.55, 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

В этой строчке

```
if arr[number] == result:
```

вы пытаетесь получить элемент массива, подставляя в качестве индекса сам элемент. Когда алгоритм доходит до значения `0.55`, возникает ошибка. В данном случае `number` -- это и есть сам элемент массива.

Нужно сделать, например, так (кусочек кода):

```
for number in arr:
    if number == result:
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен индекс уникального элемента, то так:

```
print(*[arr.index(i) for i in arr if arr.count(i) == 1])
```

Если нужен сам элемент, то так:

```
print(*[i for i in arr if arr.count(i) == 1])
```