# Найти уникальный номер

Tags: python-3.x, list, словари, производительность, tuple

Дан список, список может быть оочень большим.

Необходимо: найти уникальный элемент списка, например:

arr = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ] ответ: 2 или arr = [ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ] ответ 0.55

Мои решения:
через кортежи:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    return [i for i in [(i,arr.count(i)) for i in arr] if i[1] == 1][0][0]
```

через словари:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
   d = {i:arr.count(i) for i in arr}
   return [i for i in d if d[i] == 1][0]
```

Но оба они не проходят, пишет:

Max Buffer Size Reached (1.5 MiB)

что мои решения превысили максимальный размер буфера...
помогите, подскажите как же оптимизировать по быстродействию...

Comment: Простой банальный (немодный) цикл? Возьми два первых элемента. Если они равны, то просто идёшь циклом по списку пока не найдёшь отличающееся значение. Если не равны, то один из них уникальный. Сравни с третьим элементом и выбери.

Comment: А не вот эти вот страшные квадратичные конструкции…

Comment: мега аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888830/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-python